# Why is blocked edge port still forwarding in RSTP on Juniper EX Switch?

Tags: juniper, spanning-tree

I have one EX Switch connected to my laptop on port ge-0/0/9

```
set protocols rstp interface ge-0/0/9 edge
set protocols rstp bpdu-block-on-edge
commit

root> show spanning-tree interfaces
```

it still indicates that my ge-0/0/9 is Forwarding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edge configuration is not about disable RSTP for port. "Edge" means you are sure, that it is not a port to another switch, and you need to exlude it from STP calculation. This port is always in Forwarding state, if everything is ok (without incoming wrong BPDU).

But if switch receives BDPU from this port, it should shut down the port or remove edge configuration from the port. In your case, because of "bpdu-blocl-od-edge" I believe port will be turned off (you can read this for details https://www.juniper.net/documentation/en_US/junos/topics/reference/configuration-statement/bpdu-block-on-edge-spanning-trees-ex-series.html).

Of course, switch continues to send BPDU to this port, because we need to detect loop if it occurs.

Comment: Interestingly enough, there is a "disable" option for ports (like access ports to end devices most likely) that you DON'T want participating in the STP process.

Comment: @JoshGarmon47, it is a good idea to leave STP enabled on the access interfaces. If someone connects two of the together, then it will save you from crashing your network.